# Backbone.js - Collection within Model - Object function (a){return new n(a)} has no method 'has'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

I am getting an

```
Object function (a){return new n(a)} has no method 'has'
```

error on calling the `fetch()` method on my model. Heres the code:

```
var Exercise = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        idAttribute: 'e_id',
        e_id: "-1",
        exerciseName: "Exercise",
        exerciseDescription: "Address",
        exerciseURL: "vimeo.com",
        reps: "0",
        sequence: "0"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        alert("Exercise!");
    }
});

var ExerciseList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "/getWorkoutList.php",
    model: Exercise,
    initialize: function() { }
});

var Workout = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "/getWorkoutList.php",
    url: function() {
        return this.urlRoot + "?workoutID=" + this.get('workoutId');
    },
    defaults: {
        idAttribute: 'workoutId',
        workoutId: "-1",
        workoutName: "WorkoutName",
        workoutDescription: "WorkoutDescription",
        exercises: new ExerciseList()
    }, 
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this); 
        directory.renderWorkout(this);
    },
    parse: function(response) {
        return response;
    }
});

var WorkoutList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "/getWorkoutList.php",
    model: Workout,
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this); 
    },
    parse: function(response) {
        return response;
    }
});

var WorkoutView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    className: "workout-container",
    template: $("#tmp-workout").html(),
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this); 
        this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function(){
        console.log("WorkoutView");
        var tmpl = _.template(this.template);
        this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    //add ui events
    events: {
        "click #workout-details": "getWorkoutDetails"
    },

    getWorkoutDetails: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.model.fetch();
    }
});

var ExerciseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "exercise",
    className: "exercise-container",
    template: $("#tmp-exercise").html(),
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this); 
        alert("ExerciseView");
    },
    render: function(){
        console.log("render exercise view");
        var tmpl = _.template(this.template);
        this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var WorkoutListingView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#workouts"),
    initialize: function() {
        var collection = new WorkoutList();
        collection.fetch();
    },
    render: function() {
        var that = this;
        _.each(this.collection.models, function(item){
            that.renderWorkout(item);
        });
    },
    renderWorkout: function(item) {
        var workoutView = new WorkoutView({
            model:item
        });
        this.$el.append(workoutView.render().el);
        var that = this;
        _.each(workoutView.model.get('exercises').models, function(exercise) {
            that.renderExercise(exercise);
        });
    },
    renderExercise: function(item) {
        var exerciseView = new ExerciseView({
            model:item
        });
        this.$el.append(exerciseView.render().el);
    }
});
```

Everything works fine when I am retrieving the Workout Collection the fist time. However, when I call `getWorkoutDetails`, I get the error. By inserting alerts and `console.logs` in `parse()` of Workout Model, I've found out that it does get the correct response from server, but for some reason, its giving this error.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: try with this  _(this).bindAll();
            this.render = _.bind(this.render, this); 
            this.render();
            this.model.bind('change:value', this.render);

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I cannot figure out where do you want me to put me to put this piece of code:

_(this).bindAll(); this.render = _.bind(this.render, this); this.render();

Do you want me to put it in the initialize() of WorkoutView?

Comment: ah sorry, yes in initialize() WorkoutView  ;)

Comment: No problem :) But still the same problem. And WorkoutView's render function didnt get called either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after spending a lot of time in the beautiful world of minified javascript spaghetti, I found out that the underscore.js version I was using didnt had the function 'has' in it. Updating underscore.js from 1.2.2 to 1.4.4 solved the problem. Also, my backbone.js version is 0.9.1